# Register(?) libspotify.dll

Tags: dll, spotify, libspotify

Trying to play with some libraries/wrappers for libspotify(.dll) using C# on a Windows machine. I do how ever get errors on this dll. I have the DLL in the same directory as the exe and it is found. The exceptions are thrown in swedish, but it says something like "Could not find any start address with the name sp_session_init in the DLL-file libspotify". (Yea, i'll work on getting english errors instead..)

If I try to register the DLL (with `regsvr32 libspotify.dll`) I get an error something like "The module libspotify.dll was readed, but the start address for DllRegisterService was not found. Check that libspotify.dll is a valid DLL- or OCX-file and try again".

Yes, the DLL is downloaded from https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/ and it is the windows version.

And yes, I've found tons of threads regarding DLL-trobles but none of these solutions has worked yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Almost any library named "libXxx" is a C library.  The universal glue language.  That requires using pinvoke from a .NET program.  Invariably today, somebody has done this before.  It is nearly impossible to not find it, the [*second* hit](https://libspotifydotnet.codeplex.com/) when you google "libspotify".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing the same.
Seems to me that you've started with the same sample code as I did.
(I then decided to go through the entire API step by step)

The current lib does not contain the init method. What you want to use is

> [DllImport("libspotify")]
>
> [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
>
> internal static extern sp_error sp_session_create(IntPtr configPtr, out IntPtr sessionPtr);
>
> sp_error res = SpotifyApi.sp_session_create(configPtr, out sessionHandle);